# How to compile multiple java source files dynamically

Tags: java, compilation, javacompiler

Is there any way to programatically generate class files from .java files present in a folder.
There are examples using  JavaCompiler.CompilationTask  for compiling single java files.But i need to to generate class file from multiple couples .java codes(generated from JAXB gen).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Java Compiler API to compile multiple java files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112640/using-java-compiler-api-to-compile-multiple-java-files)

Comment: Already tried...not working..throwing this exception:    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All compilation units must be of SOURCE kind
 at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:183)
 at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:68)
 at MyGrp.com.myArtifact.Main.compile(Main.java:154)
 at MyGrp.com.myArtifact.Main.main(Main.java:121)

Comment: Can't do much with that stacktrace if you don't show code. Edit a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) into your question so we can see how you are attempting to do it. Also, edit in that the duplicate doesn't help because (enter reason here; in your case, exception is thrown, edit the stacktrace into your question as well)

Answer (score 0):

Use Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac ...");

Comment: There are multiple .java files...compilation fails if the parent class is first compiled instead of  child class....They .java files are from jaxb generated...

Comment: you can fix this if you make sure all your compiled classes are contained in the classpath